# Increase Array size in a for loop

Tags: mql4

I everyone, i would like to record some indicator's values in an array through a script.
 I would like to increase the array size and record the value in the array when a condition is satisfied. 
I've tried several ways to write it but none of these works.
Any suggestions?

```
void OnStart()
  {

   double   max[]; // array of indicator values
   ArrayResize(max,0);

   int copied= 50000;

//--- copy the values of main line of the iCustom indicator
   for(int i=1;i<copied;i++)
     {
      if(Buy_M15(i))

      ArrayResize(max,ArraySize(max)+1);
      max[ArraySize(max)]=maxM1(i);
     }

//--- open the file for writing the indicator values (if the file is absent, it will be created automatically)
   ResetLastError();
   int file_handle=FileOpen(InpDirectoryName+"//"+InpFileName,FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_CSV);
   if(file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
      PrintFormat("%s file is available for writing",InpFileName);
      PrintFormat("File path: %s\\Files\\",TerminalInfoString(TERMINAL_DATA_PATH));
      //--- first, write the number of signals
      FileWrite(file_handle,"best perf");
      //--- write the time and values of signals to the file
      for(int i=1;i<ArraySize(max);i++)
         FileWrite(file_handle,max[i]);
      //--- close the file
      FileClose(file_handle);
      PrintFormat("Data is written, %s file is closed",InpFileName);
     }
   else
      PrintFormat("Failed to open %s file, Error code = %d",InpFileName,GetLastError());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it is advised to resize array buffer with some extra space after it in case you suspect you will need to increase it. Each time the program executes `ArrayResize(arrayName,newSize,extraSpace=0)`, it copies the whole array into a new place and adds one (in your case) extra value. This means if you end with 1,000 elements array, then you have to copy array with 1 element, then array with 2 elements, then ... then with 999. not good - use extraSpace parameter, in such case array is resized without copying, it helps a lot.

Second, when you type `max[ArraySize(max)]=maxM1(i);` you should receive an error because array of N elements has pointers 0 to N-1, and you try to assign some value to N+1 position. `max[ArraySize(max)-1]=maxM1(i);` should help

Also, when you open / create a file with `FILE_READ` - you will probably wish to read it, but do you? Drop `FILE_READ` to save some time when debugging next time (you may do a mistake and add new lines at end of the file, if removing `FILE_READ` your file is erased once you open it